# Pass parameters to CompletableFutures in Java

Tags: java, method-reference

Using Java, I introduced myself to the wonders of `CompletableFuture`s.

There's one thing I do not understand, how do I pass parameters to the executed functions?

Sample code:

```
CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(MyClass::myMethod, ???args???);
```

Comment: Use a lambda expression.

Comment: Like `CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(()->classInstance.myMethod(args...));` ?

Comment: Yes, that's right.